# Crear Layout Producto Magento 2

Tags: layout, magento2

Hola a todos y gracias por vuestra ayuda. Estoy empezando con Magento 2 a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

En Magento 1 yo trabajaba las vistas de algunos productos añadiendo un layout personalizado en el apartado de diseño de cada producto que lo necesitara, añadía algo algo así:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog-view-for-phone/view-for-phone.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Estoy intentando crear el layout personalizado para mejorar la vista de los atributos en ciertos productos de Magento 2 sin éxito. Algo así:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/view/view-for-phone.phtml</argument>
        </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Mi ruta absoluta al fichero .phtml sería esta:

```
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/view-for-phone.phtml
```

Me da la sensación que estoy poniendo la ruta mal, ¿puede ser?.

He probado diferentes formas de ponerla y estoy empezando a ofuscarme ya que no parece que funcione de ninguna forma...¿Alguien me echa un cable?